# What is causing these html hyperlinks to have different height than the rest of the text?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink

I have a few links that are slightly smaller (at their bottom part) than the rest of the text and I don't understand why is that and what I did wrong that could have caused this.

The problem exists [here](http://lab.cmikavac.net/autokana/) on following links: *github*, *link*, *email*, *comment* and *lab*.

If i move the list outside of #top_container, then the size becomes normal and the weird spacing at the bottom of these links disappears.

Does anyone have an idea of what I did wrong? Thanks.

Comment: I don't find any problems in the website at that link.

Comment: Agreeing with SidMS... I can't recreate the problem.  I did notice that you're using em font sizes.  em values are relative to the containing element, so something that's .5em within an element that's already applying .5em will ultimately come out at .25em.  Might be worth looking into that as a possible culprit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see is, actually, an optical illusion generated by the contrast between white and red fonts. Also, you use bold fonts for links which only add to the impression that these fonts are smaller. Try changing their colors and weight.

I've uploaded a screenshot of a fragment of your page. That line can be used as a base to compare a little more accurately these fonts. Hope it helps.

[image]

EDIT. I use Firefox. Maybe in other browsers bold fonts are rendered a little different and the discrepancy is real (not an optical illusion as I've supposed the first time).

Comment: well, I really feel quite silly about this now.. and I tried it in different browser, kept staring at it and it indeed does feel like the font size for the links is smaller (bold or not), but now that I tried to make a screenshot myself and to draw a line like you did to compare the sizes - sizes are actually the same. I also tried changing the color of the links to white and the effect does not appear then. thank you.